# User permissions not changing on docker hub

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I have an organization on dockerhub named 'acme', inside org 'acme' i have a separate user 'bob' who is part of the 'owners' team.

I have granted the 'owners' team 'admin' access to a repository 'fish'.

When i try and push a new build & tag to that repo, i get the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: No such image: acme/fish:latest
```

When i look at the API , i see the following permissions.

```
"permissions": {
    "read": true,
    "write": false,
    "admin": false
}
```

When i look at docker info i see:

```
Username: bob
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
```

What do i need to do in order to enable 'bob' user to have write access?

*(Actual credentials have been redacted)*

Comment: If you go to the repository's url, and choose the "Collaborators" tab, what do you see?

You may need to add the "owners" team to that specific repository with admin (or at least write access)

Comment: its showing 'owners' - 'admin'